# Try Catch Exception running SQL Query Twice

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

This function seems to be running the SQL query twice, any idea why?

When I run an insert SQL query it inserts the data but also brings back this error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__SD_T_Cod__143F51C51BFD2C07'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SD_T_Code'. The duplicate
>   key value is (t-503).

This seems to tell me that it is running the SQL twice, it gets inserted the first time, but the second time it doesn't insert because the id already exists (it got created with the first insert)

```vb
Public Function InsertUpdateData(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand) As Boolean
        Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbConnect").ConnectionString
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(connStr)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = con
        Try
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Return True

        Catch ex As Exception

            Response.Write(ex.Message)
            'resultSQL.Text = ex.Message
            Return False

        Finally
            resultSQL.Text = "Successfully Saved"

            con.Close()
            con.Dispose()

        End Try

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Check if your page do some postback. But i think if you add a brake point in your code you will find why...

Comment: i think the page is doing some postback, but if i put an `if not ispostback` statement the code won't execute

Comment: Just debug it :). Also i do not know where in you page you are calling the insert. You must not do the insert on page_load. You have to do it on button_click or somewhere else like this.

Comment: What's the value of `cmd.CommandText`?

Comment: How and when is the function InsertUpdateData called? I can't imagine that your problem exist in this function.

Comment: You can try executing your insert query in SQL Management Studio or other SQL client. This way you will check if its problem with database  (incorrect query, some trigger maybe?) or with application (for example double postback).